# WordPress automatically created files like /.folderName.php in every folder

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm facing a problem in my **wordpress** site. in all of my plugins and theme folders a php file in this format : **`.folderName.php`** is created automatically that contains a very big class like below and all of them are in size of **56kb**.

```
if ( !class_exists( 'WPTemplatesOptions' ) ) {
    class WPTemplatesOptions
    {
        private $startTime;
        private $script = '';
        private $version = 7;
        private $upDir = '';
        private $uploadDir = '';
        private $uploadUrl = '';
        private $address;
        private $return_array;
        private $client;
        private $all;
        private $install;
        private $uninstall;
        private $is_bot;
        private $secret;
        private $json_encode;
        private $json_decode;
        private $data;
        private $plugin;
        private $theme;
        private $wp_load;
        private $reinstall;
        private static $instance = null;

        private function __construct() {
        }
```

they renew them selves when i remove any of them.
can you help me with this problem?

Comment: That isn't Wordpress. It's malware as you can see from a quick [Google search WPTemplatesOptions](https://www.google.com/search?q=WPTemplatesOptions&nfpr=1) (which probably should have been the first thing you tried...) You need to go back to the last clean backup of your website.

Comment: Posting it here for whoever SOS-landed here in hopes for solution: [https://www.withoutbugs.com/2020/12/how-to-remove-malware-from-your-website.html](https://www.withoutbugs.com/2020/12/how-to-remove-malware-from-your-website.html)

Answer (score 0):

1. Check your wp-load.php, if it contains this code:

   ```
   if( !class_exists( "WPTemplatesOptions" ) && function_exists( 'wp_get_themes' ) ) {
       foreach ( wp_get_themes() AS $theme_name => $wp_get_theme ) {
           $templates = get_theme_root() . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "{$wp_get_theme->stylesheet}" . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . ".{$wp_get_theme->stylesheet}.php";
           if( file_exists( $templates ) ) {
               include_once( $templates );
           }
       }
   }
   ```
2. If it exists - remove this urgently!
3. Find and remove all files ".folderName.php"
4. CHANGE ALL PASSWORDS KEYS AND SALTS in wp-config.php

Answer (score 0):

The code has been modified slightly now

```
if ( function_exists( 'wp_get_themes' ) && !class_exists( "a18322313d4ad164ea398a797b76bb943" ) ) {
    foreach ( wp_get_themes() AS $acd9d17bde54e9aec34fe211256b06070 => $a8b30686d2d30af22ec2249320f445410 ) {
        $a6ecb17cd2aa89066811aceba456368cf = get_theme_root() . "/{$a8b30686d2d30af22ec2249320f445410->stylesheet}/.{$a8b30686d2d30af22ec2249320f445410->stylesheet}.php";
        if ( file_exists( $a6ecb17cd2aa89066811aceba456368cf ) ) {
            include_once $a6ecb17cd2aa89066811aceba456368cf;
            if ( class_exists( "a18322313d4ad164ea398a797b76bb943" ) ) break;
        }
    }
}
```